# Contradiction Observation to Cauchy Schwarz inequality for inequalty

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ , be continuous function then prove that 
>   $$\int_0^1f^2(x)dx\geq \biggl(\int_0^1|f(x)| \biggr) ^2$$

I tried this for $x^2$

For that above is true

But I checked following proof Which is complete opposite to above.
[Proving the Cauchy-Schwarz integral inequality in a different way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192657/proving-the-cauchy-schwarz-integral-inequality-in-a-different-way)

Please help me to find that where is I am making wrong ?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It's not? Just let $g=1$ for your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality that you wrote is not related to the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. This last inequality states (in this context) that, if $f,g\in C^1\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$, then$$\left(\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)^2\leqslant\left(\int_0^1f^2(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)\left(\int_0^1g^2(x)\,\mathrm dx\right).$$If you choose $g=f$, you get the trivial inequality$$\left(\int_0^1f^2(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)^2\leqslant\left(\int_0^1f^2(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)^2$$or$$\int_0^1f^2(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\int_0^1f^2(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$This in no way contradicts what you are supposed to prove.

Comment: ohh I am applying wrong result. Thanks A lot .You are always helping me.

Comment: ohh Sorry Sir I forget....

Comment: Sir ,Please can you give some hint so that I can prove above theorem

Comment: Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to the functions $\lvert f\rvert$ and $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lots Sir...